# Beginner LISP: At what stage in a Do Loop can I implement an IF condition?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, do-loops

I am designing a simple function (for class, so please no complete done-for-you answers) that returns the first odd integer in a list, or 'none if there are none.

I have a working code for finding the odd number:

```
(defun first-odd (lst)
  (do ((numbers lst (cdr numbers)))
      ((oddp (car numbers)) (car numbers))))
```

but what I can't seem to figure out is where to place the IF conditional (which is required for the assignment) to produce "NONE" if the list is only even #s, or presumably NIL.
Do I make the exit point of the DO itself the IF conditional? Or does it go before/after?

I'm working on something like this (although I have a feeling it's wrong):

```
(defun first-odd (lst)
  (do ((numbers lst (cdr numbers)))
      ((if (oddp (car numbers))
           (car numbers)
           (print 'none)))))
```

Or can someone advise me on 'where' to place the IF? Sorry for the truly beginner takes, but the prof didn't provide much documentation for DO and I've been scratching my head all weekend. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The function's spec is at odds with the overwhelming convention: a function that finds and returns integers that might not be found should return `nil`. Or possibly `(values)`: an empty set of values that turns to `nil` if the caller tries to get a return value anyway.  Also note that printing `none` is not the same as returning `none`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DO takes three arguments: the first one is the list of variables with their initial values and the subsequent values; the second is the terminating condition, i.e. when to exit the loop and the result to return; the third one is the body of the loop, and it's optional.
The second element contains an implicit if.
Your first code looks good with one exception: have you considered what happens if there are no odd elements in the list? You need then to test for the end of the list (i.e. when list is nil). Then, the result will depend on whether you exited the loop because an odd number was found, or a nil list. That's where you can use IF.

Comment: Thanks! So the IF will occur after the DO closes, correct? The indentation would be in-line with "(do", evaluating whatever the loop 'spits out'?

Comment: The second (car numbers) is the result to be returned after the end condition has been met. Replace that with: IF list-is-nil then return nil else return (car numbers)

Comment: So I've got "(if (endp numbers) (return 'none) (car numbers))" as the second element of the exit condition, but I still get an error that "the value of EXCL::X is NIL, which is not a type of INTEGER" and I'm just not sure what's generating that. Should my IF *be* the exit condition itself? Or do I preserve the oddp exit and add the IF as a conditional following it? Or do I need something above that to check for the nil list? Sorry but I can't figure out where the issue is.

Comment: @Zarathustra: You are nearly there: your code is going to look like `(do ((numbers list) (cdr numbers)) (<end-test> <result>))`, as it does now.  `<end-test>` needs to: check if you are out of list and only if you are not check if the first element is odd.  `<result>` needs to do mostly the same, except it needs to return the odd element, or `none`.  Hint: what does `(or <something> (explode-the-world))` do if `<something>` is true, and how can this help you?

Comment: An interesting thing to know is that each clause of the function OR is evaluated sequentially and  only if the previous clauses are false. So (or (null x) (oddp x)) means: if x is null, exit with value true, otherwise if x is odd exit with value true, otherwise exit with value false (nil).